# Left join in SubSonic Problem

Tags: join, subsonic

I'm a beginner in SubSonic and I'm using version 2.1. I'd like to perform a left join in this query. The query looks like:

```
select ... 
from tableA
left join tableB on tableA.Cola=tableB.Colb and tableB.Colc='some value'
```

I want to know how to perform the `and tableB.Colc='some value'` condition. I tried something like this:

```
new SubSonic.Select().From("tableA").LeftOuterJoin
("tableB","Colb","tableA","Cola").AndExpression("Colc").IsEqualTo("some value")
```

but the generated statement is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you want , but the best way to do things like this in subsonic is with views, So create the select as a view and then use the view object in your code. In 3+ the linq makes it alot easier to accomplish what you are trying

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the and part of your query should really be a where condition (you're trying to filter your results based on the value of tableB.Colc being equal to 'some value'). So what I think your sql query should look like is:

```
select ... 
  from tableA left join tableB on tableA.Cola=tableB.Colb 
  where tableB.Colc='some value' or tableB.Colc is null
```

If that is the case then in SubSonic you would do:

```
new SubSonic.Select()
   .From("tableA").LeftOuterJoin ("tableB","Colb","tableA","Cola")
   .Where("Colc").IsEqualTo("some value")
   .Or("Colc").IsNull()
```